# Error al conectarse a base de datos en MySql con Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos en MySql pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

[image: Db]

Leí que eso podía deberse a la configuración en application.properties y la modifique a como vi en varias respuestas, pero el error persistió:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:IP AQUI}:3306/DB AQUI?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=USUARIO
spring.datasource.password=CLAVE
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true

spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true

spring.datasource.validation-interval=10000
spring.datasource.log-validation-errors=true
```

Mis archivos del proyecto son los siguientes:

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.estudiantes</groupId>
    <artifactId>control</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>control</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme por favor, para ver en que parte estoy cometiendo el error, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por el repositorio a maven tuve el mismo error, debes cambiar esta  depencia:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

por:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Ten en cuenta que se elimina el tag **scope** por la **version** de mysql que debas usar.

Más [info(pero en ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192560/spring-boot-client-plugin-auth-is-required/53194358#53194358), es mi post pero en Stackoverflow ingles.